# Android double Dialog box

Tags: android, dialog

I show a **Dialog box** to the user while loading a page.Would there be any problem if i show **another Dialog box** before dismissing the previous one?

I have tested it and its working fine.Just wanted to make sure.

I need to do this because-- When the user clicks on a button i show **loading** dialog box and users identity is verified in the background.If i dismiss this dialog box there the lag of say 2 sec( specially when network is very slow),before the user moves to the next activity.

I am showing another dialog box so that the user stays in that activity before all background work is done.

Answer (score 0):

There would be no problem, when you are displaying one or two dialog boxes, but If you increase the number of dialog boxes, then your application becomes complex for users and it don't meet the user-friendly principles. you can use more dialog boxes in different places in your app.If you try to show more than three or four dialog continously, then your application will not meet the quality.

Comment: Thanx.Just wanted to make sure. I am using just 2.The second one visible when network is extremely slow otherwise not.Anyway thanx :)